# will pt9 plugins work on pt10

Tags: pro-tools, compatibility

i am presently using pt8.04 that was packaged with several plug in. I have the opportunity to purchase pt9 with many plug ins, will these plug-ins work in pt10 too?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They will work in Pro Tools 10. It's Pro Tools 11 that will not use the older format plug-ins.